# iOS can't set background color for FXBlurView

Tags: ios, uiview, blur

I'm using [FXBlur](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) to achieve blur-effect for an underlying view. But the background color which I set is never seen while running.

I have a "`Main View`" inside which there is an `Image` and a `Blur View`. `Blur View` has a grey background.

The `Image` is getting blurred but I can't see the **grey color** which I had set for the `Blur View`. No matter what I try, I can't set the backgrund color and achieve the blur effect simultaneously.

What might be the issue? Is there any workaround?

`EDITED` :

```
self.blurView.dynamic = NO;
self.blurView.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.blurView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;
```

Comment: what kind of syntax is that? Can you show us your example code?

Comment: Sorry for that. Edited. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Do you tried another Image or Colore for FXBlur? Maybe the Imagescolors overtake the gray overlay..

Comment: you meant the tintColor ? It is the one to go for..

Comment: @JeslyVarghese tried that. No change..

Comment: @SaifDeen Yups. Tried with other image. Still the same.

Comment: Try to show some Code... Maybe theres a problem..

Comment: @SaifDeen Edited. I have included the code.

Comment: Did you checked the FAQ of FXBlur? Maybe last FAQ fits in..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The blurView tintColor uses additive blending, so making it grey won't have much effect.

If you want to add a grey overlay to darken your blur view, add a subview with a partially transparent grey backgroundColor inside the blurView.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to achieve the same using a `Toolbar` and a `CALayer`. Here is the code :

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.blurView.frame.size.width, self.blurView.frame.size.height)];
[self.blurView addSubview:toolbar.superview];

CALayer *extraColorLayer = [CALayer layer];
extraColorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, toolbar.frame.size.width, toolbar.frame.size.height);
extraColorLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:126/255 green:126/255 blue:126/255 alpha:0.4].CGColor;
[self.blurView.superview.layer addSublayer:extraColorLayer];
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Your app did not get rejected for using the toolbar class?

Comment: @MichalShatz Nop. Did you face any problem?